# Full Text Search Finding Word Only Occasionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with a full text index.  This query returns 2 results:

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE ContentForSearch LIKE '% mount %'
ORDER BY 1
```

This query returns 1 result:

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE CONTAINS(ContentForSearch, '"mount"')
ORDER BY 1
```

Adding a new instance of the word "mount" to the table does show up in the search.  Why?

I've already checked the stopwords list as best as I knew how to.  This returns no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fulltext_stoplists
```

This returns no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords
WHERE stopword like '%mount%'
```

I also checked to see if the index was up to date, this returned the current time (minus a few minutes) and a 0, indicating idle:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ss, FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('SampleTableCatalog','PopulateCompletionAge'), '1/1/1990') AS LastPopulated,
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('SampleTableCatalog','PopulateStatus')
```

I also did some searches in the string that doesn't show up in the CONTAINS result to see if the ASCII values were strange (and can provide queries if needed), but they were exactly the same as the one that did show up.

On one copy of the database, someone ran:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON SampleTable SET STOPLIST = OFF;
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON SampleTable SET STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

and that seemed to fix it, but I have no idea why, and I'm uncomfortable making changes I don't understand.

**UPDATE**
Stoleg's comments led me to the solution eventually.  Full text indexing was somehow turned off on a certain database server.  When that database was then restored to another server, those entries that didn't get indexed on the first server were still not indexed even though the new server was properly updating the index.  I found this by using Stoleg's queries to check which rows were missing from the index, and then checking the modified date for those rows (which luckily were stored).  I noticed the pattern that rows from the dates when the database was on the other server were not in the index.  The solution on the problem server was to turn on full text indexing and rebuild the catalogs.  As to how the indexing got turned off, I don't understand it myself.  The comment from the DBA on how he solved it was "I added full text search as resource to cluster node. "

Comment: You might look into what all is registered as a word breaker, and possibly filters as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207002.aspx  I'm not sure how those would relate to how resetting the stoplist fixed it though.

Comment: Please provide values that show with `LIKE` and with `CONTAINS`

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using? What are the results when you run `select @@version`

Comment: Also do you have any results that are NOT 32 for the LUCode and RUCode when you run this query against your sample table? `SELECT m.StringMatch
  , LEFT(m.StringMatch, 1) as L1
  , UNICODE(LEFT(m.StringMatch, 1)) AS LUCode
  , right(m.StringMatch, 1) as R1
  , UNICODE(right(m.StringMatch, 1)) AS RUCode
FROM SampleTable st
CROSS APPLY (SELECT substring(ContentForSearch, charindex(' mount ', ContentForSearch), 7) AS StringMatch) as m
WHERE st.ContentForSearch LIKE '% mount %'
;`

Comment: I don't see anything unusual as a word breaker.  SQL Server version: "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 28 2012 08:42:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)"

Comment: @BateTech All 32 :(  Cool query though.

Comment: @Stoleg With like results are " Mount Everest is near New Delhi" and " This is Mount Kilimanjaro".  With CONTAINS, only the first one shows up.

Comment: What is column datatype? Search term should be `NVARCHAR`. Try `CONTAINS(ContentForSearch, N'"mount"')`. Is there really a space as first character in ' Mount Everest ...'? Waht is Db collation?

Comment: Try this to check if "mount" got its way to the index: `select * from sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document
( 
    DB_ID('database_name'),     
    OBJECT_ID('table_name') 
)`

Comment: @Stoleg It's NVARCHAR(MAX).  I tried N'"mount"' with no luck.  There really is a space at the beginning.  Database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  "mount" is in the index for the row that works, and not in the index for the row that isn't returned.  Great suggestions!  But no luck...

Comment: There should be a reason why it does not get to the index in second instance. May I ask you to _drop_ and recreate index. Also can you post output of the query above (useful bit).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious question is: Is 'mount' in your stoplist?

Microsoft [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx) shows you how to query and update your stop words.

You might also want to review the [general info on stoplist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280518.aspx) from Microsoft.

ADDED

Don't take as insult (not that you sounded insulted). Way too many times, people say they have checked something when they only thought they had -- looking at the wrong database, etc. So wanted you to make sure. I interpreted your some of the time as works with like, not with contains, so I thought it was more likely actually the stoplist.

The only other "obvious" solution would be to rebuild the full text index -- with the thought that changing the stoplist has the same effect on the other database. I suppose you could restart the server first too. But, as another mysterious solution, not a first choice.

Comment: As I said in the question, I have checked the stoplist and do not see "mount".  Also, it seems like it wouldn't EVER find the word "mount" if it were int he stoplist, but it is finding it some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

> Changes the full-text stoplist that is associated with the index, if any.
>
> OFF
>   Specifies that no stoplist be associated with the full-text index.
>
> SYSTEM
>   Specifies that the default full-text system STOPLIST should be used for this full-text index.
>
> stoplist_name
>   Specifies the name of the stoplist to be associated with the full-text index.
>
> For more information, see Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search.

This just removed and reset the stoplist to system default.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the extra spaces in '% mount %'
try:

`SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE ContentForSearch LIKE '%mount%'
ORDER BY 1`

Comment: This doesn't explain why contains doesn't get these results.  Taking out the spaces just shows more irrelevant results involving words like mountain.